# No heading Javascript JSON Array -> CSV Export

Tags: javascript, json, csv

Hi Guys the export works but i dont have a heading :/

i dont know what is my Problem
Information: i'm getting my data from a database it's a Json Array

Can someone help me?

My Code:

```
        var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
        $("#csv").click(function(){
        // Iterating through all the objects
         data.forEach(function (infoArray, index) {

         // Fetching all keys of a single object
         var _keys = Object.keys(infoArray);
         var dataString = [];

//Test for my heading   
    //  var heading = ["Timestamp ; ToolVersion ; MonitorType ; SerialNumber; MonitorRevision ; TestScript ; TestCase ;TestCaseVersion ;TestScope; Duration; Result; ClickCount ;MorbalWaitAverage; MorbalWaitMin ; MorbalWaitMax ; TimingProblems ; AbortedRetries ; OperationRetries ; AcknowledgeAverage ; IncreasedUpdateTime ; FalseScrolls "];
        //dataString.push(heading);

        if(index==0){
         [].forEach.call(_keys, function(inst, i){
            dataString.push(inst);
         });
         dataString = dataString.join(";");
         csvContent += index < data[0].length ? dataString + "\n" : dataString;
         dataString = [];
        } else{

        [].forEach.call(_keys, function(inst, i){
            dataString.push(infoArray[inst]);
         });


          dataString = dataString.join(";");
          csvContent += index < data.length ? dataString + "\n" : dataString;
          }
        });


        var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
        link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");
        link.click(); 

        });
```

Comment: `//dataString.push(heading);` is commented out, so you're not using the headers at all in this piece of code.

Comment: no the heading is in my data.. that was only a test

Comment: Then you have to specify how you want the headers to appear in the csv file.You'll want to add each header either when pushing to the dataString, or later when building up the csvContent;

Comment: perfectly when i'm pushing the dataString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
    //--------------------------- CSV EXPORT --------------------------------

    var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-16,";
    $("#csv").click(function()
    {
        var _keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
        dataString = "_"+_keys.join(";");
        csvContent += dataString + "\n";
        // Iterating through all the objects
        data.forEach(function (infoArray, index) {

            var dataString = [];

            [].forEach.call(_keys, function(inst, i){
                dataString.push(infoArray[inst]);
             });
              dataString = dataString.join(";");
              csvContent += index < data.length ? dataString + "\n" : dataString;
    });


    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");
    link.click(); 

    });
```